# Will this code not result in a deadlock? Java Threads locking

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

So the thing is, I want to be able to do this with my class.

object.lockAccess();
object.doSomething();
object.doAnotherThing();
object.doAnotherThingYet();
object.unlockAccess();

So the other thread will not be able to access my class methods while locked.
Here is the implementation I did, I was wondering if someone got a better idea, or if it may fail.

```
private boolean locked = false;

public void lockAccess() throws Exception
{
    while(!tryToLock())
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

public void unlockAccess() throws Exception
{
    while(!tryToUnlock())
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

private synchronized boolean tryToLock()
{
    if(locked)
        return false;
    else
    {
        locked = true;
        return true;
    }
}

private synchronized boolean tryToUnlock()
{
    if(locked)
        return false;
    else
    {
        locked = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it better to use what java natively provides you, e.g. synchronization, locks, java.util.concurrency? Also, that code is not going to work, because variable 'locked' can have different values for different threads (see java memory model).

Comment: @Stas Or just the Java intrinsic locks. Also `try`-`finally` is useful.

Comment: @Stas, note that `locked` is protected by the same lock across threads, so it is safe.

Comment: There is a slight bug in the `tryUnlock()` method too, a missed `!` in the if condition.

Comment: @Dimitris Andreou. True. Havn't noticed synchronized there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(!tryToLock())
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Terrible idea.

Use a [Lock implementation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) from java.util.concurrent.

Or just a `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your intent it'd be far easier to just do this (since you can use any object as a mutex in Java):

```
synchronized( object ) {
  object.doSomething(); 
  object.doAnotherThing(); 
  object.doAnotherThingYet();  
}
```

If you need finer control, and a tryLock in particular, then look at the "Lock" interface and the classes that implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Your `tryToUnlock()` method is incorrect, but otherwise it would technically work.

Most Java programmers would do something more like this, though:

```
synchronized (object) {
    object.doSomething();
    object.doSomethingElse();
    ...
}
```